# Link / anchor has only the effect of adding to the context menu

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, contextmenu

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qy10scga/)

```
<a href="//google.com">
  <button onClick="event.stopPropagation();">
    click
  </button>
</a>
```

What Im after:

- I want "copy link location" in my context menu.
- Besides that I want the `<a>` to be NOOP (no operation).

=> I have the benefit of "copy link location" and at the same time no redirect-stuff is happening and the normal button functionality is in operation.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier than I thought.

```
<button onClick="event.preventDefault();"> ...
```

[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)